# How to split numpy array based on rows and keep those values into different arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this numpy array:

```
sample= 
[[0.8 0.2 0.7 0.1]
 [0.7 0.5 0.5 0.0]
 [0.7 0.5 0.5 0.1]
 [0.7 0.5 0.3 0.3]
 [0.9 0.6 0.2 0.1]
 [0.8 0.6 0.5 0.0]]
```

I want split it based on the rows(6) as well put those values into different numpy arrays.
For example:

```
sample_row_1 = [0.8 0.2 0.7 0.1]
sample_row_2 = [0.7 0.5 0.5 0.0]
sample_row_3 = [0.7 0.5 0.5 0.1]
sample_row_4 = [0.7 0.5 0.3 0.3]
sample_row_5 = [0.9 0.6 0.2 0.1]
sample_row_6 = [0.8 0.6 0.5 0.0]
```

Comment: Users on StackOverflow will help you, **after you help yourself**.  Learn how to post good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  And http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get the most out of this site.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a compelling reason why basic array indexing via `A[i]` is insufficient and you *need* to extract to multiple variables.

And, if there is a compelling reason, you shouldn't define a variable number of variables. Use a dictionary instead:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(16).reshape((4, 4))

arrs = {i: A[i] for i in range(A.shape[0])}

print(arrs)

{0: array([0, 1, 2, 3]),
 1: array([4, 5, 6, 7]),
 2: array([ 8,  9, 10, 11]),
 3: array([12, 13, 14, 15])}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or put them in a list of ndarrays:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(16).reshape((4, 4))

y = [a for a in A]

print(y)

# and access by index
print(y[0])
```